# Display min and max on different rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is the table im working with

| length | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-10-01 10:56 |
| 10 | 2012-10-1 09:56 |
| 8 | 2012-11-03 05:34 |
| 15 | 2012-11-03 06:21 |
| 3 | 2012-11-03 01:10 |
| 6 | 2012-10-01 03:21 |

I would like it to display

| length | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-10-01 10:56 |
| 10 | 2012-10-1 09:56 |
| 3 | 2012-11-03 01:10 |
| 15 | 2012-11-03 06:21 |

So for each different day get the min max and display them on different rows.

I've tried a few different things, but the closes I've gotten is just displaying the min max regardless of day.

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE length
IN (SELECT MIN(length) FROM t), (SELECT MAX(length) FROM t));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `DATE(date)` to ignore the time part of each datetime. Also, it seems you need to insert a `0` to `2012-10-1` to make it parsable for SQLite.

```sql
SELECT MIN(length), date FROM t
GROUP BY DATE(date)
UNION
SELECT MAX(length), date FROM t
GROUP BY DATE(date);
```

But it makes more sense to keep the maximum in a different column than the minimum:

```sql
SELECT MIN(length), MAX(length), date FROM t
GROUP BY DATE(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Window functions are an option. There are many different options.

For example, you could use `LEAD` and `LAG`.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      prevVal = LAG(t.date) OVER (ORDER BY t.date),
      nextVal = LEAD(t.date) OVER (ORDER BY t.date)
    FROM t
) t
WHERE t.prevVal < CAST(t.date AS date)
   OR t.prevVal IS NULL
   OR t.nextVal >= CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, t.date) AS date)
   OR t.nextVal IS NULL;
```

Or partitioning it and using `ROW_NUMBER`.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(t.date AS date) ORDER BY t.date),
      nextVal = LEAD(t.date) OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(t.date AS date) ORDER BY t.date)
    FROM t
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
   OR t.nextVal IS NULL;
```